# TSV Matrix as Scatterplot in D3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a 1000(rows)x100(columns) Matrix in a TSV file where each cell is an integer. I want to do an Scatterplot of the data, the X axis will be the rows (1000) and the columns the Y axis. Each value will be represented as a circle that will be bigger if the value is bigger.

At first I have tried to load the data with D3.js:

```
 d3.tsv(Data_url, function(matrix_data) {
  console.log((matrix_data));
}
```

And I'm getting just an unidimensional array of 1000 objects, I don't know why.
Furthermore I want to paint these data as explained before, so I need the row and column number, because they are data indeed. I mean, de 0 to 100 columns, are percent, and the 0 to 1000 rows are length so I will need something like:

```
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(row_number); })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(column_number); })
    .attr("r", function (d) { return r(d); });
```

But I can't find something to get the row_number and the column_number. 
I have done another approach using 'Papaparse' to read the data and it works fine. Even using JSON this way:

```
 matrix = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matrix_data));
```

I just want to understand how it should be done in D3.
Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Can you update your question to include a snippet of you TSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given matrix-like data of:

```
18  12  14  15  17  14  15  16  16  15  15  14
11  13  15  16  14  14  15  16  16  16  10  18
...
```

Here's a quick way to plot it:

```
// grad the data as text
d3.text("data.tsv", function(text) {

  // parse the data, this will produce an array of arrays
  // where the outer array is each row, the inner each column
  var data = d3.tsv.parseRows(text); 

  // set your domains to be the lengths of your data with some padding
  x.domain([-0.5, data.length + 0.5]);
  y.domain([-0.5, data[0].length + 0.5]);

  // we are going to use a nested selection
  // the outer represents a row and is a svg g
  var rows = svg.selectAll(".row")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'row');

  // the inner selection is a col and contains the points
  // which are circles
  rows.selectAll('.point')
    .data(function(d){
      return d; //<-- return each point
    })
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'point')
    .attr('cx', function(d,i,j){
      return x(j); //<-- the 'j' is the index of the row
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d,i,j){
      return y(i); //<-- the 'i' is the index of the column
    })
    .attr('r', function(d,i,j){
      return d; //<-- the d is the value in the matrix
    })
    .style('fill', 'steelblue');
```

---

Full working example is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TnU9dA41cCO8SHOWVVLE?p=preview).